# Mac OS X (Mavericks) - how to wake from screensaver by just moving mouse?

Tags: osx-mavericks, screensaver

I used to be able to wake my MacBook Pro from the screensaver by just moving the mouse, but this no longer works after I upgraded to OS X 10.9.2 (Mavericks). I've been told this is a feature, but I prefer the old behavior.

Does anyone know how to change this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is in computer sleep, the only way to wake is pressing a key on the keyboard, clicking the mouse or pressing the power button. If in display sleep (e.g. with a graphic or picture(s)) on the screen, swiping the trackpad will work.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. So it is no longer possible to wake up the computer using just the mouse/trackpad in Mavericks?

Comment: This is correct. You most click the trackpad or press a key